# Mail send with PHP in outbox of a user?

Tags: php, email, smtp, phpmailer, exchange-server

I need to send mail from my PHP app, I wonder if I authenticate as a exchange user via PHPMailer, does my mails send from my app will be on the outbox in the MS Outlook of this user ?

Thanks

Comment: If you use IMAP then potentially yes. But not with SMTP, no.

Answer (score 1):

On most mail servers, no, this doesn't happen automatically, but you can do it yourself. [The gmail example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps#L91) shows how to save a sent message to your outbox using IMAP; it will be nearly identical for Outlook. Alternatively, BCC the original message to yourself and you'll receive a copy of everything you send, which provides a similar effect.